# How to link a ressource out of bundle in symfony2 config.yml

Tags: symfony, twig

Using this configuration I can successfully access to my twig extension :

```
services:
  foo.twig.extension:
    class:  Bundle\HelloBundle\Extension\MyTwigExtension
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }
```

But now I would like to host this extension out of a bundle for use it anywhere. I need something like that: (The following code doesn't work)

```
services:
  foo.twig.extension:
    class: "%kernel.root_dir%\Resources\Extension\MyTwigExtension
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put it in any directory which is handled by autoloader (or you can add to the autoloader).

In other words you should give the **class name** in the configuration and not the **class path**. As long as it's autoloaded it'll work.

For example you might put your extensions into library called *TwigExtensions* in a *src/TwigExtensions* directory:

```
services:
      foo.twig.extension:
        class: "TwigExtensions\Extension\MyTwigExtension
        tags:
          -  { name: twig.extension }
```

This way your extensions will be Symfony independent.

Good examples of similar setup are [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and [DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle).